# 0-1 Knapsack with penalty for under and overweight cases

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem

Assume a classic 0-1 knapsack problem but you are allowed to overflow/underflow the sack with some penalty. X profit is deducted for every unit overflow (weight above max capacity) and Y profit is deducted for every unit underflow (weight below max capacity).

I thought of sorting all items by the ratio of profit to weight and then try to fill the sack like a normal knapsack problem then for remaining weight and items I calculate extra profit by taking the underflow, overflow in consideration.

This solution fails in some cases like when there are 3 items with weight 30,20,10 and profit 30, 25, 20 respectively. Max weight allowed is 39, underflow penalty is 5 and overflow penalty is 10.

My solution was to solve it like normal knapsack then considering penalties so it gives the solution of selecting items of weight 20,10 but then it does not add the item of weight 30 as its penalty is higher than profit. The optimal solution should be selection items of weight 30 and 10. The only thing I can think of now is to brute force which should be avoided if possible. If anyone could think of any other solution, that'd be great!

Comment: Why did you add tags for 3 different languages, when your question seems to be language-agnostic?

Comment: Those were the languages I know. Anyways, edited the tags now.

Comment: Seems fundamentally harder than an ordinary knapsack, since the way penalties are assessed at the end of the selection means that it isn't easy to see how the penalties can be taken into account when solving sub-problems. A dynamic programming approach thus seems problematic. On the other hand -- maybe just solve the sub-problems as ordinary knapsack problems, and just bring in the penalties at the end.

Comment: @john that's what i tried doing but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I wonder why my question got 2 downvotes hmm

Comment: I added some details to my answer, which should be enough for you to get working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break it into two subproblems, one with an underweight penalty and one with an overweight penalty. More specifically, you can solve the problem by solving two different [integer linear programming problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), and taking the best of the two solutions:

Say that you have `n` items of weights `w1,w2,...,wn` and values `v1, v2, ...,  vn`. Say that the weight capacity is `C`, the penalty for undeweight is `A` and the penality for overweight is `B` (per unit).

In both problems, let the binary decision variable be `x1, ..., xn` indicating whether or not the corresponding item is selected.

Problem 1)

```
max v1*x1 + v2*x2 + ... + vn*xn - A*(C - w1*x1 - w2*x2 - ... - wn*xn)

subject to

w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... + wn*xn <= C
```

Note that via algebra the objective function is the same as the affine expression

```
(v1 + A*w1)*x1 + ... + (vn + A*wn)*xn - A*C
```

and is maximized at the same values `x1, ..., xn` which maximize the purely linear function

```
(v1 + A*w1)*x1 + ... + (vn + A*wn)*xn
```

This subproblem can be solved using any ILP solver, or just as an ordinary knapsack problem.

Problem 2)

```
max v1*x1 + v2*x2 + ... + vn*xn - B*(w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... + wn*xn - C)

subject to

w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... + wn*xn >= C
```

which can be solved by maximizing the linear objective function

```
(v1 - B*w1)*x1 + ... + (vn - B*wn)*xn
```

Again, that can be solved with any ILP solver. This problem isn't a knapsack problem since the inequality in the main constraint points in the wrong direction, though there might be some way of reducing it to a knapsack problem.

**On Edit**. The second problem can also be solved as a knapsack problem -- one in which you decide which items to not include. Start with the solution in which you include everything. If this isn't feasible (if the sum of all weights doesn't exceed the capacity) then you are done. The solution of problem 1 is the global solution. Otherwise. Define the *surplus*, S, to be

```
S = w1 + w2 + ... + wn - C
```

Now, solve the following knapsack problem:

```
weights: w1, w2, ..., wn //same as before
values: Bw1 - v1, Bw2 - v2, ..., BWn - vn
capacity: S
```

A word on the values: `Bwi - vi` is a measure of how much *removing* the ith object helps (under the assumption that removing it keeps you above the original capacity so that you don't need to consider the underweight penalties). On the one hand, it removes part of the penalty, `Bwi`, but on the other hand it takes some value away, `vi`.

After you solve this knapsack problem -- remove these items. The remaining items are the solution for problem 2.

Lets see how this plays out for your toy problem:

```
weights: 30, 20, 10
values: 20, 25, 20
C: 39
A: 5  //per-unit underflow penalty
B: 10 //per-unit overflow penalty
```

For problem 1, solve the following knapsack problem:

```
weights: 30, 20, 10
values: 170, 125, 70  // = 20 + 5*30, 25 + 5*20, 20 + 5*10
C: 39
```

This has solution: include 20, 10 with value of 195. In terms of the original problem this has value 195 - 5*39 = 0. That seems a bit weird, but in terms of the original problem the value of using the last two items is 25 + 20 = 45 but it leaves you 9 units under with a penalty of 5*9 = 45 and 45 - 45 = 0

Second problem:

```
weights: 30, 20, 10
values: 280, 175, 80  // = 10*30 - 20, 10*20 - 25, 10*10 - 20
S: 26  // = 30 + 20 + 10 - 39
```

The solution of this problem is clearly to select 20. This means that 20 is selected for *non-inclusion*. This means that for the second problem I want to include the objects of weights 30 and 10.

The value of doing so is (in terms of the original problem)

```
20 + 20 - 10*1 = 30
```

Since 30 > 0 (the value of solution 1), this is the overall optimal solution.

To sum up: you can solve your version of the knapsack problem by solving two ordinary knapsack problems to find two candidate solutions and then taking the better of the two. If you already have a function to solve knapsack problems, it shouldn't be too hard to write another function which calls it twice, interprets the outputs, and returns the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use standard dynamic programming.

1. Let's compute whether the sum `s` is reachable for all `s` from `0` to the sum of all elements of the array. That's exactly what a standard dynamic programming solution does. We don't care about penalty here.
2. Let's iterate over all reachable sums and choose the best one taking into account the penalty for over(or under)flow.

Comment: How does this differ from brute-force? The dynamic programming approach to a standard knapsack doesn't compute all reachable `s` but only ones which satisfy an optimality condition.

Comment: Can you code this in c/c++? From what I can understand from this is that you are suggesting to brute force.